# MySql Replication over SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, replication

I have a bit of a unique situation, and I haven't been able to find any resources online addressing it, so here goes.

I have a given server A (mysql id=1)  and a remote mysql server B (mysql id = 2)

I have an SSH tunnel that is established from server A -> server B, and in that tunnel, i forward server B 3306 to a localport (say 1234)

I also do not have the ability to reverse map this, so my ssh command looks like

ssh -L 1234:remote_server_b:3306 user@gateway -i my_key.pem

so on server A, to connect to mysql on server B, i use mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P1234  and i can access the mysql server B without issues.

Now, i want to setup replication from A (master) to B (slave).  however from server B i cannot access server A, only from A->B over the SSH tunnel.

in all the mysql replication documentation, i need to establish the SSH tunnel from the slave server (and not the master in my setup)

does anyone know how to do this, or point me to some documentation about the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

To replicate a db , you must :

- do a full copy of the db
- configure a mysql replication stream on the slave to the master and the slave  connect and will pull binary log .

Implementation are documented here .

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-implementation.html

You can use SSH to a tunnel or a  reverse tunnel .

tunnel in ssh can be both ways , so you can map a local port to a remote port, or map a remote port to a local port .

On server A , this command will setup a double tunnel .

```
ssh -R 6464:127.0.0.1:3306 -L 6565:127.0.0.1:3306  serveurB
```

Extract from man page of `ssh`

```
 -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
 Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be 
 forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.

 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
 Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be 
 forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.
```

Another solution is to use `socat` a powerful network tool , so it must be  installed on the server B  , and you can do this

```
 while ( true ) ; 
 do 
      socat EXEC:"ssh SERVER_B 'socat - TCP4-LISTEN:6464,reuseaddr'"    \
                                                       TCP4:localhost:3306 ;
 done
```

Comment: apologies, i dont have the ability to reverse map the tunnel. i have updated the above ticket

Comment: @user1772250 It is not a 'ticket' it is a question on Stack Overflow, and StackOverflow is not a product support site that issues tickets.

Comment: is there a way to do it if i cannot have any access from the remote slave out to the master?  i just want to force feed the master down to the slave.

Comment: No ,  you can not , please read  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-implementation.html